# Setting selected DropDownListFor item

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I cannot get the `DropDownListFor` to set the selected `StateCode` using the view model below.

**EDIT**

Code altered per the answer given below.

**Model**

```
public partial class ZipCodeTerritory
{
    public string ChannelCode { get; set; }
    public string DrmTerrDesc { get; set; }
    public string IndDistrnId { get; set; }
    public string StateCode { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime? DisplayEndDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdateId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model**

```
    public ZipCodeTerritory editPage { get; set; }

    //Constructor
    public ZipCodeEdit()
    {
        SetDropDowns();
    }

    //Drop down list objects
    private string[] states = new string[] { "AL", "AK", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "IA", "ID", "IL", "IN", "KS", "KY", "LA", "MA", "MD", "ME", "MI", "MN", "MO", "MS", "MT", "NC", "ND", "NE", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NV", "NY", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "US", "UT", "VA", "VT", "WA", "WI", "WV", "WY" };
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StateCodes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ChannelCodes { get; set; }

    //Set state code drop down list
    private void SetDropDowns()
    {
        AgentResources db = new AgentResources();

        //Set stat code drop down items
        StateCodes = StateCodes = states.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s, Text = s });

        //Set channel code drop down list
        ChannelCodes = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                        select z.ChannelCode).Select(x => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = x,
                            Value = x
                        }).Distinct().ToList();

        db.Dispose();
    }
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, string searchZip, bool searchActiveOnly, 
        string searchDate, string searchState, string searchTerritory, string searchChannel)
    {
        if (!Security.IsZipCodeViewOnly(User)) return RedirectToAction("Message", "Home", new { id = 1 });

        ZipCodeEdit pageItem = new ZipCodeEdit();

        pageItem.searchZip = searchZip;
        pageItem.searchActiveOnly = searchActiveOnly;
        pageItem.searchDate = searchDate;
        pageItem.searchState = searchState;
        pageItem.searchTerritory = searchTerritory;
        pageItem.searchChannelCode = searchChannel;
        pageItem.editPage = db.ZipCodeTerritory.Find(id);

        return View(pageItem);
    }
```

**View**

This is for an edit page, so the view will need to load a `ZipCodeTerritory` object's properties. Using this set-up, the `DropDownListFor` for `ChannelCode` is not only populated properly but the correct value is selected. `StateCode`, however populates as it should but `AL`, the first item, is always selected. Cannot get the `StateCode` value of the `ZipCodeTerritory` object to be the default selected item.

```
@model Monet.ViewModel.ZipCodeEdit


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.editPage.ChannelCode)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.editPage.StateCode, new SelectList(Model.StateCodes, "Value", "Text", Model.editPage.StateCode))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.editPage.ChannelCode)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.editPage.StateCode)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.editPage.StateCode, Model.StateCodes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.editPage.StateCode)
    </div>
```

Comment: I can't see the execution of SetDropDowns() therefore I wonder, who set the StateCodes in the first place? Can you access the StateCodes as type of IEnumerable<SelectListItem> and simply build the List of SelectListItem in the getter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your View, change your DropDownList to this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.editPage.StateCode, Model.StateCodes)
```

Also, the states private property do not have to be of type SelectList. It should be a string array like below:

```
private string[] states = new string[] { "AL", "AK", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "IA", "ID", "IL", "IN", "KS", "KY", "LA", "MA", "MD", "ME", "MI", "MN", "MO", "MS", "MT", "NC", "ND", "NE", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NV", "NY", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "US", "UT", "VA", "VT", "WA", "WI", "WV", "WY" };
```

Then, you will define the StateCodes property like this:

```
StateCodes = states.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s, Text = s });
```

By the way, View Models should be simple POCO classes. Do not initialize your View Model properties inside the View Model. Do that in your Controller.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I need to tweak the `DropDownListFor`, however. When the page loads it simply says `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem` for all 50 items.

Comment: Can you update your code with the changes you have made to the DropDownList?

Comment: Ugh.. now I'm back to displaying all the states in the drop down list but not having the correct one selected.

Comment: I tried the code here, and it works. Please update your code with the changes you made, so I can tell you what is that you are doing wrong.

Comment: I'm assuming that `db.ZipCodeTerritory.Find(id)` returns a ZipCodeTerritory object that has a StateCode.

Comment: FWIW, you do not need to do `new SelectList(Model.StateCodes, "Value", "Text", Model.editPage.StateCode)` in the call. Just `Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.editPage.StateCode, Model.StateCodes)` is sufficient. As long as you have an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, the call can handle it.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Updated the post,btw.

Comment: Sorry, you are also correct that the `ZipCodeTerritory` has a `StateCode`. The class above in the Model section of my post is the definition of `ZipCodeTerritory`.

Comment: @NealR, does the StateCode property of editPage have a value? If you put `@Model.editPage.StateCode` in your View, can you see a value on the page?

Comment: @ChrisPratt, that's what I thought too. Initially my answer didn't have "Value" amd "Text", but that didn't work. You can try it.

Comment: @ataravati: If you actually go so far as to define a `SelectList`, then you must specify "Value" and "Text", even though you hand it a list of `SelectListItem`s. However, I just fed the `DropDownListFor` an `IEnumerable<SelectListItems>`, *not*, a `SelectList`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, you're right. But, I need the SelectList in order to define the selected item.

Comment: @ataravati: No, you don't. `DropDownListFor` makes sure the value of the model property it's fed is selected in the select list.